# Can this sequence of if's be written more elegantly?

Tags: go

```
if v, ok := os.LookupEnv("IDAASHTTPPORT"); ok {
    c.HTTPPort, _ = strconv.Atoi(v)
}
if v, ok := os.LookupEnv("IDAASDBNAME"); ok {
    c.DBUserName = v
}
if v, ok := os.LookupEnv("IDAASDBPW"); ok {
    c.DBPasswd = v
}
if v, ok := os.LookupEnv("IDAASDBPORT"); ok {
    c.DBPort, _ = strconv.Atoi(v)
}
if v, ok := os.LookupEnv("IDAASDBHOST"); ok {
    c.DBHost = v
}
```

'c' is the following struct

```
type Configuration struct {
    HTTPPort   int
    DBUserName string
    DBPasswd   string
    DBPort     int
    DBHost     string
}
```

I only want to update the struct field if the environment variable exists. Seems like some little cute map iterator or something like that would work, but I can't figure out a nice solution.

Comment: what are the values if not set?   if they are default (empty), then just do `c.DBUserName = os.Getenv("IDAASDBPW")`

Comment: and, `c.HTTPPort,_ = strconv.Atoi("IDAASHTTPPORT")` which will leave it zero if env var missing

Comment: If you want to do this in a generic way, you could add struct tags to the fields that give the environment variable name and data type. You could then write a function to populate the fields using reflection. That way, all you have to do if you ever add a new field is define the field with the appropriate tag.

Comment: @DavidBudworth, what you don't see is that I have defaults and check a TOML file for config first, then override if there is an environment variable that exists so I can support 12-factor in the future for a Docker or serverless deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some helper functions:

```
func setIntFromEnv(val *int, envName string) {
  if v, ok := os.LookupEnv(envName); ok {
    *val, _ = strconv.Atoi(v)
  }
}

func setStringFromEnv(val *string, envName string) {
  if v, ok := os.LookupEnv(envName); ok {
    *val = v
  }
}

// From your main function.
setIntFromEnv(&c.HTTPPort, "IDAASHTTPPORT")
setStringFromEnv(&c.DBUserName, "IDAASDBNAME")
etc...
```

This only works if you're ok ignoring a string env var that you're trying to parse as an int. Its relative elegance is also debatable.

Comment: Could we go further and make this a single helper using type switch on 'val' and type interface{}?

Comment: You can, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you. The [tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) should have what you need.